# Can't access endpoint on exposed port in docker-compose but can ping that container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    expose:
      - "2181"

  kafka:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    expose:
      - "8778"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:8778
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_OPTS: '-javaagent:/usr/jolokia/agents/jolokia-jvm.jar'

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:latest
    links:
      - "kafka"
      - "zookeeper"
    environment:
      JOLOKIA_AGENT_URL: http://kafka:8778/jolokia/
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING: http://zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

Example:  I can `ping kafka` successfully from `telegraf`.  I can successfully hit the endpoint I want from the `kafka` container when I'm `exec`ed into that container (`curl` from localhost when inside it).  I **cannot**, however, reach the endpoint `/jolokia/read` exposed in the `kafka` container at port `8778` from the `telegraf` container.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to build a Kafka container?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the links section. This has been deprecated by Compose for years.

Then, Compose starts its own network bridge layer, so if you exec into telegraf or zookeeper containers, `ping kafka` should work, therefore DNS would be working and so curl should as well...

Note: adding Jolokia to Zookeeper should also be done

I'll also point out that the Confluent Helm Charts already provide Prometheus and Jolokia integration